# Error: "there is no package called ..." and trying to use install.packages to solve it

Tags: r, package

The R studio I have in my university computer gives me an error when I try to download different packages, whereas when I'm with my laptop in the university server, I don't get this error. Because of this, I don't think that there is some kind of a proxy/server problem.

```
library(readr)
Error in library(readr) : there is no package called 'readr'
```

I also tried to download the package using R.exe program or download other packages and it gave me the same error.

After looking for a solution in the internet, I found this script:

```
install.packages('readr', dependencies = TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

But it downloaded many different packages: [image: picture]

I would like to know the reason why RStudio gives me this error and what happened when I tried to download readr package using install.packages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `Error in library(readr) : there is no package called 'readr'`

This means that you don't have the package `readr` installed on your computer.

You then installed it with

```
install.packages('readr', dependencies = TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

which is good. Most packages are not "stand-alone", they use other packages too, called dependencies. Because you used the default `dependencies = TRUE`, all the dependencies (and their dependencies) were also installed.

You can look at the CRAN page for `readr`: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=readr to see its dependencies (anything in the "Depends" or "Imports" fields is required). And of course you need the dependencies of those dependencies, etc. Now that `readr` is installed along with its dependencies, you can run `library(readr)` to load it.

Comment: Thank you! It seems it was a very basic knowledge.. But I'm a little bit confused because I looked my old scrips (and they're not very old because my computer is new) and I have never used install.packages in my laptop, yet the library() script has always worked. Why would that be?

Comment: Some packages come pre-installed. You can see the default list [in the official R-FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Add_002don-packages-from-CRAN). If you are using RStudio, it installs a few more packages too.

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining! :) Somehow my university computer doesn't have the pre-installed packages which my laptop has. Readr is one example but also dplyr. I wonder why. I have installed myself both R and RStudio in them.

Answer (score 2):

Because you set `dependencies = TRUE` it installed all the dependencies for the package `readr`

Those several packages you listed are considered dependencies for `readr`.

You get that initial error when a package has yet to be downloaded.