# i need to install rqpd R package for quantile regression

Tags: r, package, quantile-regression

i am doing a Quantile regression project. i have the R codes. i needed to install rqpd package for that. I find this code for installing the package :

```
install.packages("rqpd", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

it installed but after that when I want to load the package it gives me this error :

> Error in library(rqpd) : there is no package called ‘rqpd’

Should i load that after installing like other R packages?
Could you please help me ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "there is no package called ..." and trying to use install.packages to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395807/error-there-is-no-package-called-and-trying-to-use-install-packages-to-so)

Comment: Are you sure that it installed correctly? Did you get any messages / warnings / errors at all when installing?

Comment: I have been able to install the R package with :

install.packages("rqpd", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

You can also perform a quantile regression with the quantreg R package : 

install.packages("quantreg", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

Comment: Which version of R are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing it directly with the code is not possible.

First, you must download the package from the following link.

http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/rqpd_0.6.tar.gz

Run the following command when you have the file in your working directory.

```
install.packages("/workdir/rqpd_0.6.tar.gz")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).